# Creating a Lead from a Button

Tags: apex, javascript, button

I'm looking to create a lead from an account using a button. When I go to create this lead, I get the following error. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my approach/code?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}

var Lead = new sforce.SObject(Lead);

Lead.FirstName = 'XXX';
Lead.LastName = 'YYY';
Lead.Status = 'Unqualified';
Lead.Company = '{!Account.Name}';
Lead.Owner = '{!Account.OwnerId}';

var result = sforce.connection.create([Lead]);

if(result[0].success == 'true'){
    alert('An unqualified lead was successfully created.');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix you have to pass sobject name as a string to to the sfroce.sobject

you are missing ""

```
var Lead = new sforce.SObject("Lead");
```

Also as a best practice use success and failure messages to see what is going wrong.

```
if(result[0].getBoolean("success")){ 
//redirects/post save logic
} 
else{ 
alert( 
"Could not Create Record. Error: " + 
result[0].errors.message 
); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with the SOAP API very much, but one approach (which I just implemented and checked in my DEV org) is to use a flow instead, and trigger this flow from the button. This way your logic would be completed using point and click config, and calling this flow would be a single line url in your button.

I used the following page as a general guide to figure it out: https://salesforcesidekick.com/2015/06/25/assign-to-me-button/

You would first need to create a flow with a single Record Create set as the Flow Start point (do this by clicking the green plus button that appears when hovering over it).

Set the Create Record to create a Lead, and then add each of the fields you want to populate under the Field section, and set them to new variables (naming the variables whatever you want).

[image: options when adding Create Record step]

Save your flow as an AutoLaunched Flow, and make sure to activate it. I called mine createLeadFromAccount.

Then when creating your button set it to be **Detail Page Button** and set the behaviour to **Display in existing window without sidebar or header** and set the Content Source to **URL**. Then for the URL set it to something like the following:

```
/flow/createLeadFromAccount?FirstName=XXX&LastName=YYY&LeadStatus=Unqualified&LeadOwnerId={!Account.OwnerId}&AccountName={!Account.Name}&retURL=/{!Account.Id}
```

This should then add a button to the page, that whenever it is clicked will run the flow, and generate the lead as required.